# How to deploy MVC3 web app to Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, azure, cloud-hosting

I have created a mvc web application "TestMVCWebapp" and added a azure project "TestMVCWebapp.Azure" for the same. On the azure portal i have created website and downloaded the publish profile. But When i try to import this publish profile for the azure project then it show the error message "the file .pubishsettings does not contain valid publish setting for windows azure". When i try to import same profile to "TestMVCWebapp" then it accept the publish profile but i am using some cloud config. I want to deploy with web role.Any solutions?

I am using Visual studio 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a publish profile manually from your Azure project and try again. If it didn't work, create a package deployment and upload it through Windows Azure Management Portal.

Comment: I also sugest you to check the information from the publish profile that you've dowloaded from Windows Azure Management Portal. Try to create another publish account/password and download the publish profile again.

Comment: I have created package but i cant find any way to upload package from management portal to deploy a website.